# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable in indexing

Tags: python-3.x, zip, typeerror

Why does my code print: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable, whenever I run it? I have the following lists given below. What I am trying to do is to get the element/s in O then find its match in J. After finding the match, the index is obtained. Using this index, I will find its corresponding value in R.

```
    J = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    R = [[0, 0], [4, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [0, 3], [2, 2], [0, 0]]
    O = J[0]

    R_demand = [d for a, d in zip(J, R) if a in O]
    print(R_demand)
```

For the code above, since O = 1 in J, I should get R_demand = [0, 0] as my answer. All values in lists are integers.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `O == 1`. Which is why the conditional part of your list comprehension `if a in O` throws a TypeError. The `in` operation needs an iterable to follow it, 1 is a constant (non-iterable), so `a in 1` is invalid. If O will always be an integer, just change `in` to `==`, as in:

```
R_demand = [d for a, d in zip(J, R) if a == O]
```

But even better would be to ensure that `O` is an interable, like a set or a list. If you use `O = {1}` or `O = {3, 6, 9}` as in your comment below, then you should be able to use `in` as you previously had. Have you tried that?

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: What if O becomes a list of different J value? For example, O = {3, 6, 9}. Why do I get an empty bracket as an output?

Comment: Hello, I seem to be getting an error. The elements in O can vary. O = {1} or can be {3, 6, 9}. How can I adapt this into the conditional part of my list comprehension?

Comment: I updated my answer. In short, if you ensure `O` is an iterable, like a list or set, then using `in` should work as you originally had!

Comment: Hello! The content of O changes in different parts of my code. To account for times when it becomes an integer, I included if isinstance before the comprehension list. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

When you write the condition a in o, then o should be an iterable sequence which in your case is a number. So, it is arising an error ( int is not iterable).

Comment: I tried changing the code for when O = {4, 3, 1, 7}, but I get an empty bracket as an answer.

Comment: Hello, I seem to be getting an error. The elements in O can vary. O = {1} or can be {3, 6, 9}. How can I adapt this into the conditional part of my list comprehension?